# How getChildFragmentManager() supports all API levels

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

When there is a need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` to support lower API levels, I think using `getChildFragmentManager()` method. How this method supports all API levels?

Comment: could you refine the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both in the support library.

Comment: I have another question . both getSupportFragmentManager() and getChildFragmentManager() returns android.support.v4.app.FragmentMamager . why there is no seperate FragementManager for child.

Comment: Apparently they made a design decision to use the same class. It must operate a little bit differently when working with private child fragments, but it has the same public-facing methods so they just used the same class.

Comment: But if I use the support library, then all `Fragment` are also forced to be support library's one. It makes no sense for new devices. Is there some smart way to avoid need to modify all `Fragment` importing?